# Error from Nested Else Without If Statements VBA Excel, what am I missing?

Tags: excel, vba

I'm having the following problem. I have a spreadsheet that takes SEC data and parses it into financial metrics for me to evaluate. I am however a very bad coder, and I'm really not sure what I'm doing wrong here. I keep getting Else without If errors in the following block, at `ElseIf lngIteratorPhi = 271`. I have included the previous and following blocks if they help. Sorry if I'm missing something obvious, my brain melts at VBA for Applications.

```
ElseIf lngIteratorPhi = 270 Then   'dcf calculator EPS
    dblAverageFCFGrowthRateOverPast10Years = dblMinGrowthRate
    If IsError(Sheets("Workout").Cells(1 + lngIteratorAlpha, 105).Value) = False _
        And IsEmpty(Sheets("Workout").Cells(1 + lngIteratorAlpha, 105).Value) = False _
            And Sheets("Workout").Cells(1 + lngIteratorAlpha, 105).Value <> 0 Then
        dblAverageFCFGrowthRateOverPast10Years = Sheets("Workout").Cells(1 + lngIteratorAlpha, 105).Value / 100
    Else
         dblAverageFCFGrowthRateOverPast10Years = dblMinGrowthRate
    End If
    If dblAverageFCFGrowthRateOverPast10Years >= 0.2 Then
        dblAverageFCFGrowthRateOverPast10Years = dblMaxGrowthRate
    ElseIf dblAverageEarningsGrowthRateOverPast10Years <= 0.05 Then
        dblAverageFCFGrowthRateOverPast10Years = dblMinGrowthRate
    Else
        dblAverageFCFGrowthRateOverPast10Years = dblMinGrowthRate
    End If
    dblAverageFCFGrowthRateOverPast10Years = dblGrowthRateInGrowthStage
    If IsError(Sheets("Workout").Cells(1 + lngIteratorAlpha, 260).Value) = False _
        And IsEmpty(Sheets("Workout").Cells(1 + lngIteratorAlpha, 260).Value) = False _
            And Sheets("Workout").Cells(1 + lngIteratorAlpha, 260).Value <> 0 Then
        dblFCF = Sheets("Workout").Cells(1 + lngIteratorAlpha, 260).Value
    End If
    strGrowthPeriodCalcEqTemp = ""
    strTerminalPeriodCalcEqTemp = ""
    For n = 1 To intYearsOfGrowthStage
        strGrowthPeriodCalcEqTemp = "((1 + " & dblGrowthRateInGrowthStage & ")^" & n & "/ (1 +" & dblDiscountRate & ")^" & n & ") +"
        strGrowthPeriodCalcEq = strGrowthPeriodCalcEq & strGrowthPeriodCalcEqTemp
        If n = intYearsOfGrowthStage Then
            strGrowthPeriodCalcEq = Left(strGrowthPeriodCalcEq, Len(strGrowthPeriodCalcEq) - 2)
            strGrowthPeriodCalcEq = strGrowthPeriodCalcEq & ")"
        End If
    Next n
    dblGrowthPeriodCalc = Eval(strGrowthPeriodCalcEq)
    For n = 1 To intYearsOfTerminalGrowth
        strTerminalPeriodCalcEqTemp = "((1 + " & dblTerminalGrowthRate & ")^" & n & "/ (1 +" & dblDiscountRate & ")^" & n & ") +"
        strTerminalPeriodCalcEq = strTerminalPeriodCalcEq & strTerminalPeriodCalcEqTemp
        If n = intYearsOfTerminalGrowth Then
            strTerminalPeriodCalcEq = Left(strTerminalPeriodCalcEq, Len(strTerminalPeriodCalcEq) - 2)
            strTerminalPeriodCalcEq = strTerminalPeriodCalcEq & ")"
        End If
    Next n
    dblTerminalPeriodCalc = Eval(strTerminalPeriodCalcEq)
    dblDCFFCF = dblFCF * (dblGrowthPeriodCalc + dblTerminalPeriodCalc)
    With Sheets("Workout").Cells(1 + lngIteratorAlpha, 0 + lngIteratorPhi)
        .NumberFormat = "$???,??0.00;[red]-$???,??0.00;$???,??0.00" ' currency for under 100,000 dollars
    End With
    Else
    With Sheets("Workout").Cells(1 + lngIteratorAlpha, 0 + lngIteratorPhi)
        .Value = "NULL"
    End With
ElseIf lngIteratorPhi = 271 Then   'dcf calculator EPS
    dblAverageEarningsGrowthRateOverPast10Years = dblMinGrowthRate
    If IsError(Sheets("Workout").Cells(1 + lngIteratorAlpha, 98).Value) = False _
        And IsEmpty(Sheets("Workout").Cells(1 + lngIteratorAlpha, 98).Value) = False _
            And Sheets("Workout").Cells(1 + lngIteratorAlpha, 98).Value <> 0 Then
        dblAverageEarningsGrowthRateOverPast10Years = Sheets("Workout").Cells(1 + lngIteratorAlpha, 98).Value / 100
    End If
    If dblAverageEarningsGrowthRateOverPast10Years >= 0.2 Then
        dblAverageEarningsGrowthRateOverPast10Years = dblMaxGrowthRate
    ElseIf dblAverageEarningsGrowthRateOverPast10Years <= 0.05 Then
        dblAverageEarningsGrowthRateOverPast10Years = dblMinGrowthRate
    End If
    dblAverageEarningsGrowthRateOverPast10Years = dblGrowthRateInGrowthStage
    If IsError(Sheets("Workout").Cells(1 + lngIteratorAlpha, 11).Value) = False _
        And IsEmpty(Sheets("Workout").Cells(1 + lngIteratorAlpha, 11).Value) = False _
            And Sheets("Workout").Cells(1 + lngIteratorAlpha, 11).Value <> 0 Then
        dblEPS = Sheets("Workout").Cells(1 + lngIteratorAlpha, 11).Value
    End If
    For n = 1 To intYearsOfGrowthStage
        strGrowthPeriodCalcEqTemp = ""
        strGrowthPeriodCalcEqTemp = "((1 + " & dblGrowthRateInGrowthStage & ")^" & n & "/ (1 +" & dblDiscountRate & ")^" & n & ") +"
        strGrowthPeriodCalcEq = strGrowthPeriodCalcEq & strGrowthPeriodCalcEqTemp
        If n = intYearsOfGrowthStage Then
            strGrowthPeriodCalcEq = Left(strGrowthPeriodCalcEq, Len(strGrowthPeriodCalcEq) - 2)
            strGrowthPeriodCalcEq = strGrowthPeriodCalcEq & ")"
        End If
    Next n
    dblGrowthPeriodCalc = Eval(strGrowthPeriodCalcEq)
    For n = 1 To intYearsOfTerminalGrowth
        strTerminalPeriodCalcEqTemp = ""
        strTerminalPeriodCalcEqTemp = "((1 + " & dblTerminalGrowthRate & ")^" & n & "/ (1 +" & dblDiscountRate & ")^" & n & ") +"
        strTerminalPeriodCalcEq = strTerminalPeriodCalcEq & strTerminalPeriodCalcEqTemp
        If n = intYearsOfTerminalGrowth Then
            strTerminalPeriodCalcEq = Left(strTerminalPeriodCalcEq, Len(strTerminalPeriodCalcEq) - 2)
            strTerminalPeriodCalcEq = strTerminalPeriodCalcEq & ")"
        End If
    Next n
    dblTerminalPeriodCalc = Eval(strTerminalPeriodCalcEq)
    dblDCFEPS = dblEPS * (dblGrowthPeriodCalc + dblTerminalPeriodCalc)
    With Sheets("Workout").Cells(1 + lngIteratorAlpha, 0 + lngIteratorPhi)
        .NumberFormat = "$???,??0.00;[red]-$???,??0.00;$???,??0.00" ' currency for under 100,000 dollars
    End With
    Else
    With Sheets("Workout").Cells(1 + lngIteratorAlpha, 0 + lngIteratorPhi)
        .Value = "NULL"
    End With
ElseIf lngIteratorPhi = 273 Then
    If IsError(Sheets("Workout").Cells(1 + lngIteratorAlpha, 270).Value) = False _
        And IsEmpty(Sheets("Workout").Cells(1 + lngIteratorAlpha, 270).Value) = False _
            And Sheets("Workout").Cells(1 + lngIteratorAlpha, 270).Value <> 0 Then
    With Sheets("Workout").Cells(1 + lngIteratorAlpha, 0 + lngIteratorPhi)
        .Value = Sheets("Workout").Cells(1 + lngIteratorAlpha, 270).Value * 0.85
        .NumberFormat = "$???,??0.00;[red]-$???,??0.00;$???,??0.00" ' currency for under 100,000 dollars
    End With
    Else
    With Sheets("Workout").Cells(1 + lngIteratorAlpha, 0 + lngIteratorPhi)
        .Value = "NULL"
    End With
    End If
```

Comment: Your code starts with an `else`, but doesn't appear to have an `if`. Else conceptually doesn't make sense without an if.

Comment: Ah my apologies. There is an If statement at the very beginning, this is fairly kludged code, it starts with `lngIteratorPhi = 0  For lngIteratorPhi   = 0 To 500  
    Debug.Print lngIteratorPhi`  And then it changes into a multitude of test cases for formatting these big numbers, such as above and `If lngIteratorPhi = 2 Then
    With Sheets("Workout").Cells(1 + lngIteratorAlpha, 0 + lngIteratorPhi)'
        .NumberFormat = "$???,??0.00;[red]-$???,??0.00;???,??0.00"'
    End With`

Comment: `Else
    With Sheets("Workout").Cells(1 + lngIteratorAlpha, 0 + lngIteratorPhi)
        .Value = "NULL"
    End With` These blocks (I could see two at least) seem to be orphaned

Answer (score 0):

Oh I see now that I have an extra Else in the end. Marked as solved!

Comment: So your code works now - great! Looks terrible though (no offense intended)... feel free to post it (all!) on [codereview.se] along with a description of its purpose; reviewers will help you make it do the same thing, only much, *much* better.

Comment: @Mat'sMug Thanks! I will. I'm very new to coding in VBA and in general.